# Unresolved debugging symbols in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, cross-compiling

One of my application runing on Montavista linux in powerpc platform has crashed. The top 3 stack frames shows absolute address instead of the symbols. My build machine is hosted on a different platform and I am using a cross complier to build the application. How can I get back the symbols.

The backtrace is given below -

```
#0  0x0f272adc in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x0f3537fc in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x0f274f44 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0f276e94 in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x105c94a8 in fast_memget (module_id=0, noctets=820, err=0x3893e710) at ../common/src/portlayer.c:1305
#5  0x1055f734 in glbSipParserDecodeMessage (
    message=0x3b225e58 "SIP/2.0 200 OK\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.194.182.55:5060;branch=z9hG4bK2495419925-4086;received=10.194.182.55;ingress-zone=mxenode51\r\nCall-ID: 2469861343-4086\r\nCSeq: 6 INFO\r\nContact: <sip:4084565719@10.194"..., opt=0x3893e70c, messageLength=425, nextmesg=0x3893e898, pContext=0x3893e8cc, ppSipMessage=0x3893e6bc, err=0x3893e710) at src/sipdecode.c:6184
```

Comment: Have you compiled with -g? or with optimization (-O1, -O2, etc)?

Comment: Brady, I need to check this. Actually we have a large number of applications running on a ATCA based platform in a distributed enviroment and hence the build process is automated and managed by build engineers. What difference it would make if optimizations are enabled. Thanks for your post.

Comment: wow, that sounds very familiar. We considered ATCA once. Ive run into this problem cross-compiling from linux to Cavium Octeon (MIPS) and have especially seen when using their reference board, having compiled with optimization I cant see the symbols either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the C library (libc) with debugging information. On Debian or derived systems (e.g. Ubuntu) it's a package called `libc6-dbg`.

Comment: But the malloc symbol has been resolved correctly in stack frame 3 and it belongs to the same library libc.so.6.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the extra information in the comments, here are some things to check:

Was the application compiled with optimization (-O1, -O2, etc)? If so, recompile without these options. Ive come across this situation myself cross-compiling on Cavium Octeon (MIPS) and observed that the presence of the optimization flags caused problems seeing the symbols.

Could it be that the stack is somehow corrupted? Although if this were the case, I would think that all of the frames would be corrupt. Do you have the possibility to use something like Valgrind to see if your stomping memory somewhere? or at least run the application on Linux?

Before going any further, do you really need to know any more about those first 3 frames? Isnt knowing that it crashed in malloc enough? Maybe instead you should be considering what could cause a crash in malloc. In that same Cavium platform mentioned before, we had a problem that the system would crash if we called malloc/new when there was no memory was left :( Even after informing them of the bug, we had to use a hacky work-around. Are you checking for NULL when calling malloc/new? This could be difficult if you call it from several different places. We had new/malloc wrapped, so this was easy to do for us.

Update after more comments from OP

It shouldnt crash if you run out of memory whether or not its due to a memory leak, but try to check that malloc doesnt return NULL. You should also consider using an "out of memory handler" as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5548639/1158895).

On that same Cavium platform we had a similar memory corruption problem that was quite difficult to track down (we couldnt run it on Linux with valgrind yet). We found a way to check the validity of the internal memory headers every time we did a malloc. This really slowed it down, but ultimately it allowed us to find the problem. If you dont have access to something like this, or valgrind on linux, you could consider "wrapping" malloc/new and implementing it yourself. This would be quite complicated but could be a worst case situation.

Comment: Brady, Thanks for your informative post. 1) The stack corruption is ruled out as other stack frames are clearly visible in the core-dump. 2) The cause of malloc failure could be that we are having memory leak in the process leading to no allocatable memory left, memory corruption leading to a situation where we have memory but malloc fails due to corrupt internal memory headers structures, or we are having heavy memory fragmentation as the crash is observed after the stress tested for 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say last three frames somehow don't have valid information. Guessing: probably some assembly functions called from malloc (although those frames should probably be readable).

But since you do know the address of malloc from same library, you can calculate relative difference of PC in that frames (for example: -1f50 for frame #2). Use your cross toolchain, and to objdump -d libc.so, and check the code at malloc - that difference...